# WLST edit mode issue for managed instance

Tags: python, weblogic12c, wlst

While I had executed command `edit()` connecting to managed instance I was ended-up with the following error. How & What I have to do in order to come out of this problem.

```
wls:/offline> connect('Admin60000','sun1rise','t3://my-comm-app-serv:60001')
Connecting to t3://my-comm-app-serv:60001 with userid Admin60000 ...
Successfully connected to managed Server "MiCommApp" that belongs to domain "MiBeaDir".

Warning: An insecure protocol was used to connect to the
server. To ensure on-the-wire security, the SSL port or
Admin port should be used instead.

wls:/MiBeaDir/serverConfig>cd('/Servers/MiCommApp/SSL/MiCommApp')
wls:/MiBeaDir/serverConfig/Servers/MiCommApp/SSL/MiCommApp> edit()
Edit MBeanServer is not enabled on a Managed Server.
```

60001 is managed instance port which is one among the managed instance that runs in admin server. Admin server runs in 60000 port

Comment: Could you please paste your complete script, ".py" and ".sh" or anything else you are doing, it is hard to tell point out the issue from what you have provided.

Comment: I could do `cd('/Servers/'  'MiCommApp' '/SSL/' 'MiCommApp' )` and do `edit()` and `startEdit()` if I logged in and do through admin server. If logged in any managed instance I am facing this issue.

Comment: Ok. Please read my first comment.

Comment: I didn't run any scripts like `./wlst.sh some_program.py`, rather I had opened-up `./wlst.sh` and tried as I explained above in the question as edited now. Thanks. I am newbie. With admin server login `edit()` & `startEdit()` command works as expected.

Comment: Ok, now your problem is clear to me, please refer my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because for managed servers, WLST functionality is limited to browsing the configuration bean hierarchy. Read below excerpt from [WL official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/config_scripting/reference.html#wp1179175).

> **To edit configuration beans, you must be connected to an
>   Administration Server**, and you must navigate to the edit tree and
>   start an edit session, as described in edit and startEdit,
>   respectively.
>
> If you connect to a Managed Server, WLST
>   functionality is limited to browsing the configuration bean hierarchy.
>   While you cannot use WLST to change the values of MBeans on Managed
>   Servers, it is possible to use the Management APIs to do so. **BEA
>   Systems recommends that you change only the values of configuration
>   MBeans on the Administration Server.** Changing the values of MBeans on
>   Managed Servers can lead to an inconsistent domain configuration.

So, basically you need to connect with your Admin server (current you are getting connected with your managed server, as per logs you have provided - `Successfully connected to managed Server "MiCommApp" that belongs to domain "MiBeaDir".`) and then issue edit configurations using `edit()` and `startEdit()` WLST commands.

---

BTW, I connect to my server using following command:

- If HTTPS - `connect(url='t3s://abc.xyz.com:37001',adminServerName='AdminServer')`
- If HTTP - `connect(url='t3://abc.xyz.com:37001',adminServerName='AdminServer')`